# How to show all colors supported by bash?

Tags: bash, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

One day, I typed the command

```
echo "\033[32mHELLOBASE\033[m"
```

in the gnome bash shell. The terminal showed me a green HELLOBASH string.
I found this interesting. From my experience and serveral tests, I can change
the number 32 from 0 up to 47. Next I wrote the following code,

```
for i in {0..48};do
    echo \033[$imHELLOBASH\[033m
done
```

Of course, it doesn't work, or I cannot be here! So how to improve the above code to function?

Comment: Bash doesn't natively show colors at all -- your terminal does that. If you want to look up what your terminal can and can't support, the `tput` command looks up the right codes for colors.

Comment: ...the code you're using right now only works on *some* terminals -- on others, those codes would be garbage. Using `tput` means you always have the right code for the terminal type you're currently using.

Comment: ...see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's do this the right way -- looking up color codes in our `termcap` (or, for modern systems, `terminfo`) database using the `tput` command:

```
for ((i=0; i<=48; i++)); do
  tput setaf "$i"
  echo HELLOBASH
done
```

If you want to see all available colors on a 256-color terminal, use this code token from [BashFAQ #37](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037):

```
colors256() {
        local c i j

        printf "Standard 16 colors\n"
        for ((c = 0; c < 17; c++)); do
                printf "|%s%3d%s" "$(tput setaf "$c")" "$c" "$(tput sgr0)"
        done
        printf "|\n\n"

        printf "Colors 16 to 231 for 256 colors\n"
        for ((c = 16, i = j = 0; c < 232; c++, i++)); do
                printf "|"
                ((i > 5 && (i = 0, ++j))) && printf " |"
                ((j > 5 && (j = 0, 1)))   && printf "\b \n|"
                printf "%s%3d%s" "$(tput setaf "$c")" "$c" "$(tput sgr0)"
        done
        printf "|\n\n"

        printf "Greyscale 232 to 255 for 256 colors\n"
        for ((; c < 256; c++)); do
                printf "|%s%3d%s" "$(tput setaf "$c")" "$c" "$(tput sgr0)"
        done
        printf "|\n"
}
colors256
```

For additional background on how and why any of this works, see [the bash-hackers page on terminal codes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes).

---

As for why your original code didn't work even on terminals using ANSI color codes, by the way -- @rici pegged it correctly: Your parameter expansion was ambiguous without adding curly braces.

That is to say:

```
$imHELLOBASH
```

...needed to be...

```
${i}mHELLOBASH
```

...to avoid the shell trying to find and expand a variable called `imHELLOBASH` rather than a variable named `i`.

Comment: `termcap` or `terminfo`?  I think that is implementation dependant.

Comment: Depends on how modern your system is. These days, yes, it would be terminfo.

Comment: I thought `termcap` died out in the late 1980s, my recollection of the days of curses is a little shaky.  Where the heck did you dig-up that program from?  I'll bet you had to blow a lot of dust off it :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is not much to do with bash, more to do with the terminal driver.  Rather than trying to use control characters, I suggest you use `tput` instead, for example:

```
i=1
while (( $i < 10 ))
do
    tput setaf $i
    echo "This is $i"
   (( i++ ))
done
```