# How to change color of bash output for specific character sequence

Tags: bash, colors

I'm working on a project in which I start some servers from terminal and it displays all of the server logs as different events happen (polling messages, API calls, etc).  I'm in the middle of testing some new features and need to watch these logs as they go by (quickly) to ensure everything is working as expected.  I'm wondering if it's possible to color code certain messages that come through so I can identify them more quickly.

For example, I want to identify where a specific API call was made.  Something like "INFO:root:default: PUT /api/v0.1/something/something/mashedpotatoes".  Is it possible to change the color of that message whenever it happens to come through?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577923/how-to-show-all-colors-supported-by-bash/30578079#30578079

Answer (score 9):

You can use ANSI escape codes to do this.

```
Black        0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
Red          0;31     Light Red     1;31
Green        0;32     Light Green   1;32
Brown/Orange 0;33     Yellow        1;33
Blue         0;34     Light Blue    1;34
Purple       0;35     Light Purple  1;35
Cyan         0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
Light Gray   0;37     White         1;37
```

And use it like:

```
PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
echo "${PURPLE}INFO:root:default: PUT /api/v0.1/something/something/mashedpotatoes${NC}\n"
```

which prints it in purple.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for, but correct me if I'm wrong.  It sounds like I'd have to add that to the source of the logs?  I'm basically looking for something I can add to my .bash_profile which will parse through the logs as they appear and colorize them if they match my character sequence.  If I were to add this, to my .bash_profile, I think this would just print that sequence when opening my terminal.

Comment: @Mike You can add those codes to the output via sed, awk, etc. when you are reading the logs to display them on screen.

Comment: It might be better to use `tput` to get the codes for these colors instead of hard-coding them. Nothing guarantees these will be the correct codes for the given terminal.

Comment: In my case, `echo -e` is required